# Get specific field of model in select_related

Tags: django, django-models, optimization, django-orm

I have a query in my project:

```
qs = self.model.objects \
            .filter(user=self.request.user, pk__iexact=pk) \
            .select_related('shipping_addr', 'billing_addr', 'cart') \
            .first()
```

I want to optimize this query more than it is.
I want to get only the 'id' and 'name' fields of shipping_addr.
But this is not working:

```
qs = self.model.objects \
                .filter(user=self.request.user, pk__iexact=pk) \
                .select_related('shipping_addr', 'billing_addr', 'cart') \
                .only('shipping_addr__name','shipping_addr__id') \
                .first()
```

I know the reason that why this code is not running, I don't know what I have to do.

Comment: Why are you fetching three related models, when you only need one? And why are you using double underscores? Those will not work for selecting fields. Also you can probably just use pk=pk.

Comment: 1: This is just a sample. Not all of what I want to do. "simple better than complex"_____2:yeah, that's right. maybe it's better to use pk=pk.____ Do you have any idea about the main question?

Comment: I've answered below. I think the query in your question doesn't make much sense. `first()` and `filter()` are not needed, because you are getting one object because of the pk. You also don't need to fetch the other two models, because you're not using them afterwards. So it's just one object instead of a queryset that is being fetched together with one related object. And then just get your related fields as I've shown in the answer. No need to optimise further I think.

Answer (score 1):

`select_related()` is limited to single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

So it needs to start in the model that has the foreign key and then you can select the related parent object to be fetched as well. So your `self.model` has a foreign key to `shipping_addr`.

You want to retrieve the `shipping_addr.name` by saving an extra database hit because

```
object=self.model.objects.get(pk=pk)
shipping_address_name=object.shipping_addr.name
```

hits your DB twice. So, instead, you do:

```
object=self.model.objects.select_related('shipping_addr').get(pk=pk)
shipping_address_name = object.shipping_addr.name
```

And that way you have eliminated one database hit, because your object will be fetched from the database already including the `shipping_addr`.

Unless your `shipping_addr` has lots of fields or are very expensive to retrieve, I wouldn't bother using `only()`, but if you insist you can add it. Without seeing your model it's hard to say.